# DateTime format with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime

Can someone explain how it works? I need compare a DateTime in SQL Server with an user input.

Here an example of what I'm looking for:

```
DateTime[] dates = { DateTime.Now, DateTime.UtcNow };
Console.WriteLine(dates.Where(x => x < DateTime.Now));    // I need to know if they are the same without converting them to strings. 
Console.Read();
```

I'm using Entity Framework and in the entity class `Dates`, the attributes are DateTime and I need to compare that with a user's input, and the only solution I found was the CreateDate function.

As you know, I cannot compare the POST value directly with a Date attribute. Example:

```
db.dates.Where(x => x.StartDate < "2012-02-13 00:00:00.000")    // error, cannot compare DateTime with string
```

So, I tried converting the value to DateTime:

```
DateTime start_date = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-02-13 00:00:00.000");
db.dates.Where(x => x.StartDate < start_date )    // PROBLEM!!
```

Why? Well, the output of `start_date` is:

```
2012-02-13 12:00:00 am
```

But in the database, the end and start date are as follows:

```
2012-02-13 00:00:00.000    // all have zeros at the end
```

How can I compare the date when the input date is in `2012-02-13 00:00:00.000` format?

I don't care what to use, I just need the same format and the same data type.

Answer (score 5):

> i just need the same format

No, you don't. You need the most appropriate data type, which is `DateTime` (or maybe `DateTimeOffset`) and you need to forget about the string format.

"2012-02-13 12:00:00 am" is just a different textual representation of the value which can also be represented as "2012-02-13 00:00:00.000". Both represent midnight on February 13th 2012. So long as your database field is an appropriate `DateTime` type, it shouldn't matter at all. You *really* don't need to worry about format.

You *may* need to worry about whether the values are in UTC or local time, but that's a separate matter.

(I'd personally use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` rather than `Convert.ToDateTime`, but that's a slightly different matter.)

Comment: But here another problem. If i try to give format to input, then the result will be a string. Example: string correct_date = date.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"). How format without convert the value to string?

Comment: @user2195741: Sure, when you're formatting you need to convert to a string. But your question was how to perform a *query*, and you don't need formatting for that.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with the DateTime, you first need to figure if you want to use the date and the time when comparing. If you want to include the time, then you need to you the **Date.Now** to initialize your variable. If you don't want to include the time, just compare the date portion of the data, then you need to use the **Date.Today**.

- The **Date.Now** will always include the current time when the function was call.
- The **Date.Today** will always set the time at 00:00:00 so it won't interfere when you compare the date.

The first thing you need to check in you code is to make sure you only use the Date.Today.

Now when I look at your example, I don't see any problem.

> So, i tried convert the value to DateTime
>
> DateTime star_date = Convert.ToDateTime("2012-02-13 00:00:00.000");
>
> And lets go, lets compare again:
>
> db.dates.Where(x=>x.StartDate < start_date )//PROBLEM!!
>
> Why? Well, the output of start_date IS:
>
> 2012-02-13 12:00:00 am

When you compare x.StartDate < start_date, it is normal that you don't have any data because "2012-02-13 12:00:00" is equal to "2012-02-13 00:00:00.000". Since your dates are equal, it normal that your query return no data.